# Breakout - omission about the game. Suggestions?

Tags: c#, 2d-games, breakout

I am trying to make a copy for the breakout in C#. I am almost done with my work but I discovered something that is working wrong.

What the game is based on: the ball needs to hit the brick twice to destroy it.

And there is the problem: sometimes my ball hits the brick in the corner and destroys it instantly (the brick is untouched). Any suggestions for solving this?

I will attach a video and the code where the ball and the brick collide.

Ball, brick = pictureBox

My problem illustrated: https://youtu.be/73iaDUxo4AE

```
if (pt.Y < 0 || ball1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Player.Bounds))
                bally = -bally;
foreach(Control x in this.Controls)
{
            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "block")
            {
                if (ball1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                {
                    x.Tag = "Hit";
                    Image myimage = new Bitmap("blue_block.png");
                    x.BackgroundImage = myimage;
                    x.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    bally = -bally;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "Hit")
                    if (ball1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        score = score + 1;
                        bally = -bally;
                        this.Controls.Remove(x);
                        if(score<=5)
                            speed = speed + 1;
                    }
            }
}
```

Many thanks in advance and I hope I was specific enough. Have a nice day !

Comment: I assume `this.Controls.Remove(x);` is the line of coding removing the brick? If so, put a breakpoint on it, and see when it is being called unexpectedly.

Comment: I changed the link for the video

Comment: Yes , there is the brick removing

Comment: honestly , I am not used with those breakpoints and I don't know what to expect